# Why do I lose formatting after running javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is probably a silly question but why do I lose all the formatting when the function test() starts? What should I change in my code? I would really appreciate your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
   body {
         background: #E6E6FA;
         font-family: book antiqua;
   }
   h1, h2 {
      color: grey;
   }
</style>

</head>
<h3>Title</h3>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
    <input type="text" id="userInput"></input>
    <button onclick="test()">Submit</button>
    <p id="Demo"></p>
    <p id="Beg"></p>
    <p id="Fin"></p>
    <script>
        function test()
        {
            var nam= document.getElementById("userInput").value;
            var l = nam.length;
            var pocz = nam.slice(0,1);
            var kon = nam.slice(-1);
            document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = document.write("Your secret code: " + l + pocz + kon);
            var one = nam.slice(-1)
            if (one == "a") {
               document.write(nam.slice(0,-1) + "bbb");
            } else {
               document.write(nam + "ccc"); 
            }         


        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `document.write` is called **after** the DOM loaded, it **replaces** the document. Also you are using `document.write` incorrectly, it doesn't return anything. Just omit it and it will work fine.

```
document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = "Your secret code: " + l + pocz + kon;
```

For the other uses, do the same thing and assign the value to an element via `innerHTML`.

Please read the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) before you use an unfamiliar function.

Comment: Thanks, but after introducing your change the script stopped working completely. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in this case but it seems something's not right!

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/83s60b00/. I guess you did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I must have done something wrong, but now it works! I thought you have to use document.write in this case, thanks for explaining this! Would vote you up but my "reputation" is too low! (started learning js yesterday). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Never use `document.write`. Ever. Just don't use it. It is completely antiquated.

Felix Kling's answer will work for the first part, since you are assigning html to an element directly. but the later calls are adding more content to the document, not replacing content, so you must append new content to the document, or make another placeholder (like demo). here is how to do it with appending new content:

```
function test()
    {
        var nam= document.getElementById("userInput").value;
        var l = nam.length;
        var pocz = nam.slice(0,1);
        var kon = nam.slice(-1);
        document.getElementById("Demo").innerHTML = "Your secret code: " + l + pocz + kon;
            var one = nam.slice(-1);
            if (document.getElementsByClassName("spantext").length===0)
            {
            var text=document.createElement("span");
    text.setAttribute("class","spantext");
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(text);
            }
            else {
            var text=document.getElementsByClassName("spantext")[0];
            }

            if (one == "a") {
               text.innerHTML=nam.slice(0,-1) + "bbb";
            } else {
               text.innerHTML=nam + "ccc"; 
            }      

    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r8oz05f/)

Comment: Thank you, chiliNUT! I tried adding another placeholder which works but looks ugly (it splits the text into two paragraphs). I'll definitely experiment with appending new content!

Comment: By the way, I'm just playing around with your code but it seems I have to add something before the <script> tag?

Comment: not sure what you're referring to, the example is self contained